# Can single quotes and double quotes be used interchangeably while enclosing strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Till now whatever programming languages I have encountered use double quotes for string and single quotes for characters but some of the javascript code that I saw seemed to be using them interchangeably,is it possible?

In which situations can they be interchanged?

In which situations they CANNOT be interchanged?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'll just lay it out there that it's my personal preference to always use double quotes. I'll escape (`\"...\"`) double quotes before using single quotes even crosses my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are interchangeable, but when you open a string with one, you must close it with the same character. For instance,

`"Hello'` would not be a valid string.

EDIT: PS, this allows for you to enclose quotes in a string. For example, if you want to have the string literal "Hello", you could have

```
var string = '"Hello"'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes they can as long as you keep in mind a few main things;

1- double quotes are the preferred by the browser to se they parameters values, so you never use them when setting javascript values or function calls within the DOM.
2- double quotes are also used to specify json an properties a json string using single quotes to delimiter they key, value pairs is not valid.
3-they don't complement each other, so what one starts one must end.
4 - if you need to use the same quote inside your string you need to scape it.